# How does Flixtools work?

Tags: macos, metadata, image-recognition

I have been using an app named **flixtools** from http://flixtools.com/, It got me really curious about how it searches for the movie name. I renamed the movie file with some random text and yet it finds the correct name of the movie for finding subtitles. From a developers view I wanted to understand how it is able to find the real name of the movie file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put : the movie name is in the file's metadata.

Most media formats (jpeg, mp3, mp4, etc...) are structured so that, along with the image/music/video data, there are some metadata about the photo/music track/tv show/movie that the file contains.